# DAX SUMMARIZE miss applied slicers

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a slicer, called COUNTRY and applied to table MY_TABLE. When I calculate a measure, everything works as expected:

```
-- calculates distinct count only for COUNTRY = x
Some Measure = DISTINCTCOUNT('MY_TABLE'[SOME_COLUMN])
```

The problem is `SUMMARIZE` ignores slicer selection:

```
-- calculates distinct count accross all countries: x, y, z, etc.
Calculated Table = 
RETURN SUMMARIZE(
    'SOME_TABLE',
    [CATEGORY],
    "COUNT", DISTINCTCOUNT('SOME_TABLE'[SOME_COLUMN])
)
```

How to make `SUMMARIZE` take into account slicers?

Comment: From this thread I understand it's not possible, but still not sure https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Timeline-Slicer-with-Calculated-Tables/m-p/146014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can filter calculated table with a slicer. If you can, go for SUMMARIZECOLUMNS because this function is better optimized then SUMMARIZE, and has arguments for filtering.

[Filtering SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59931193/1903793)

If you want to stick to SUMMARIZE, you can filter your table by wrapping it with CALCULATETABLE.

```
Calculated Table =
CALCULATETABLE (
    SUMMARIZE (
        'SOME_TABLE',
        [CATEGORY],
        "COUNT", DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'SOME_TABLE'[SOME_COLUMN] )
    ),
    Dim[Color]
        = SELECTEDVALUE ( Slicer[SlicerValues] )
)
```

[Should FILTER be used inside or outside of SUMMARIZE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48370006/1903793)

Answer (score 3):

Only Measures are "responsive", calculated tables and columns get calculated and created once, when the data are loaded.

Note that if a calculated table is used inside a measure it will behave correctly, but as you may know, a measure must return a scalar value and not a table. (ie you can use summarize inside a measure, you can then filter the obtained table and return the sum of one column)